# batch change folder name by read line from text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have many folders have a file.txt. This file.txt have multy line and there is a line like this

```
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ name@company.com SMTP_Email_Address
```

and every e-mail is deffernt than other in this line in every file
how I can read the e-mail address or search about e-mail from the text file and rename the folder by this name?

If we have this line up in folder named (A) I want the batch read name@company.com and rename the (A) folder.

**its will be like this ( find `*@*.*` in file.txt / first e-mail address the batch find

if u find >> rename the folder to any name )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I believe it will work:

```
@echo off
pushd "your root location"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /srbc:"SMTP_Email_Address  *type=SZ  *[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*  *SMTP_Email_Address" filel.txt^|sort /r'
) do if exist "%%A" for %%F in ("%%A\..") do (
  for /f "tokens=3" %%N in ("%%B") do ren "%%~fF" "%%N"
)
popd
```

The FINDSTR /S option searches "file.txt" in all child folders for the email address lines. The full file path is prefixed to each found line. The SORT /R causes child folders to be listed before parents. This is important so that we don't attempt to rename a child folder after the parent has been renamed.

The IF EXIST "%%A" prevents any attempt to rename a folder after it has already been named (the folder is renamed to the first email address found).

The outermost FOR /F breaks the found lines into the path of "file.txt" and the line of text. The next FOR extracts the parent folder of the file, and the last FOR extracts the email address.

The script will of course fail to rename a 2nd folder if the same email address appears in multiple folders.

Comment: not working sorry - how i cant tell the batch if i have @ and dot this is an e-mail and this is the name what i want to be the folder name

Comment: i think this is what i want .. but need fix please

Comment: @Hauari - I don't understand your first comment. I don't understand what is not working. I edited the regex to verify the address has `*@*.*` format, without any spaces.

Comment: thank you alot :) but let me ask last qustion :  if i have xml code like this <HTTPMail_User_Name type="SZ">a@a.com/HTTPMail_User_Name> how i can but it in the same batch because this sign > i think need something deffernt - can i change the code to : 'findstr /srbc:"SMTP_Email_Address *type="SZ">  *[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]* *<" *.oeaccount^|sort /r'

Comment: the batch you create work good for only 1 folder - you must run many times to change folders name - every folder need you run the batch again - thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

**Before executing oneliner:**

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 fol1
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 fol2
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 fol3

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ cat */file.txt
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ abc@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ lmn@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ xyz@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
```

**Oneliner:**

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ for i in `ls -1`; do NAME=`awk '{ print $3}'  $i/file.txt | awk -F\@ '{ print $1}'` && mv $i $NAME ; done
```

**After executing oneliner:**

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 abc
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 lmn
drwxr-xr-x  3 sgeorge  wheel  102 Jan  6 14:18 xyz

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ cat */file.txt
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ abc@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ lmn@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ xyz@company.com SMTP_Email_Address )
```

Comment: Oh.. you want batch code. Sorry, my mistake. I overlooked and thought you want bash.