# batch code to chnage folders name after read text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, directory, findstr

Someone great in this site give me this code at [batch change folder name by read line from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14184726/1012053)

```
@echo off
pushd "your root location"  
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (  
'findstr /srbc:"SMTP_Email_Address  *type=SZ  *[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*  *SMTP_Email_Address" filel.txt^|sort /r'  
) do if exist "%%A" for %%F in ("%%A\..") do (  
  for /f "tokens=3" %%N in ("%%B") do ren "%%~fF" "%%N"  
)  
popd
```

the code find this code perfectly

`SMTP_Email_Address type=SZ name@company.com SMTP_Email_Address`

I want the code find this

```
<SMTP_Email_Address type="SZ">abc@abc.com</SMTP_Email_Address>
```

**because of this signs > < "" the code not work**

and change the folder name by the email found in the text file inside

Comment: I am trying to edit your post to make it more readable, tbh I think you should roll it back to how I put it, it makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: we do edit in same time so i dont know how u edit it :) u can do what u want brother :)

Comment: No worries bud, someone else has already edited it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i understand the question.
you need to escape the special characters with the caret sign (^)
e.g.
replace

```
"SMTP_Email_Address  *type=SZ  *[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*  *SMTP_Email_Address"
```

with

```
"^<SMTP_Email_Address  *type=^"SZ^"^>  *[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*  *^<^/SMTP_Email_Address^>"
```

Comment: oh i think i overlooked something, findstr has its own syntax(a backslash) for escaping special characters. but i tried various combinations and can't get it to work either :(

Answer (score 1):

The following will work as long as the relevant line of XML is formatted exactly as you have specified. But that is risky, because the format of the XML could change and still be valid, yet it would break this code. Batch is not a good choice for parsing XML unless you know exactly how the XML will be formatted.

*EDIT - this original code mostly worked, but it has 2 problems:*

*1) The sort operation can lead to the use of the wrong matching address line. It is supposed to use the first found matching line.*

*2) The script may attempt to rename the root location. Windows will not allow that because your batch script has its current directory set to that location.*

```
@echo off
pushd "your root location"
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=:<>" %%A in (
  'findstr /srbc:"<SMTP_Email_Address .*>[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*</SMTP_Email_Address>" file1.txt^|sort /r'
) do if exist "%%A" for %%F in ("%%A\..") do ren "%%~fF" "%%B"
popd
```

*The code below has been fixed to properly use the first matching address line. It also will not attempt to rename the root location. But other renames could fail if any process currently has a dependency on that location.*

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "YourRootLocation"
set "search=<SMTP_Email_Address .*>[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*</SMTP_Email_Address>"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'findstr /srmbc:"%search%" file1.txt^|sort /r'
) do for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%B in (
  'findstr /rbc:"%search%" "%%A"'
) do if exist "%%A" for %%F in ("%%A\..") do if "%%~fF" neq "%CD%" (
  echo ren "%%~fF" "%%B"
  ren "%%~fF" "%%B"
)
popd
```

Comment: thank u , i try this and not work  and this xml file not changed  the code same all time

Comment: @Hauari - I tested, and the original code mostly worked, except for 2 minor bugs. I've edited my answer with a new version. If that does not work for you, then the address line format in your files must not quite match what you posted. The search definition would have to change to match the format in your file.